# Get associated objects via DB access in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models: Guardian, Student and Organization. Guardian is connected to Student through a linking model and similarly Student is connected to Organization through a linking model. I need to get for every guardian, a list of (distinct) organizations and am wondering what the best way to do so is.

Currently I do it at the application level in the Guardian class

```
def organizations
  orgs = []
  students.each do |s|
    s.organizations.each do |o|
      orgs << o if !orgs.include?(o)
    end
  end
  orgs
end
```

I wonder if there's a better way to do this, preferably at the database level. Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: here's a more detailed description of my models

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end 

class Guardian < Person
  has_many :student_guardian_links, inverse_of: :guardian, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :students, through: :student_guardian_links, inverse_of: :guardians
end

class Student < Person
  has_many :student_guardian_links, inverse_of: :student, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :guardians, through: :student_guardian_links, inverse_of: :students
  has_many :student_organization_links, inverse_of: :student, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :organizations, through: :student_organization_links
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :student_organization_links, inverse_of: :organization, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :students, through: :student_organization_links, inverse_of: :organizations
end
```

Comment: You could get a better answer if you just post the relations between models more explicitly like: Guardian has_many :link_model; Guardian hash_many :students, through: :link_model

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just added those in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With relational databases is often better to think from the target set. So you want organisations with specific conditions (they have students connected to a specific guardian)

In ActiveRecord we have `joins` for this. It is a misnamer, as you still get only Organisation objects, it only uses a SQL-join to get them from the database, and you can specify conditions on the joined object.

Look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html at "Joining Nested Associations" and "Specifying Conditions on the Joined Tables"

So depending on your exact model (remember you need the backward connections) it may look like this:

```
Organinisation.joins(:students).where('student.guardian_id' => mygivenguardian.id).distinct()
```

`distinct` is important when the join can lead to multiplications of the rows, as when a guardian is connected with more then one student to the organisation.

Comment: Hey thanks.
I tried--
Organization.joins(:students).where('people.guardian_id' => 158850).distinct()
but it gives me an error
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column people.guardian_id does not exist.
(people is the name of the table students and guardians are put in and I believe it errs out since it's a self join). Not sure how to reconstruct the query. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
students.map { |student| student.orgs }.flatten.uniq
```

Really the same approach you are taking. Just using a more functional approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Guardian < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizations,
           :through => :students
  # Your existing relationships go here
end
```

This way you can simply call `guardian.organizations.uniq` to get a list of distinct organizations associated with a specific Guardian object.